# How to convert Samsung Backups

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung, calendar, samsung-kies

I backed up my calendar and contacts with Samsung Kies and switched then to cyanogen mod.
The problem is now that I can't transfer the data back via Kies.

Is there a converter for the samsung calendar format? (ssc)
I do also have a full adb backup of the phone, maybe the internal data of the phone is more useful?

I don't want to install old android again just to get my calendar back.